# Exception in Activemq with Spring

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I tried to start Apache server to run my project, but a error display in console follows:

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized)     à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) com.adweb.webapp.ApplicationListener
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception lors de l'initialisation du active MQ
        at   com.adweb.webapp.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in file** [C:\projets\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\iliadysFront\WEB-INF\classes\activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:71)
        at com.adweb.external.queue.ActiveMQService.<init>(ActiveMQService.java:28)
        at com.adweb.webapp.ApplicationListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationListener.java:45)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be rising while creating the ActiveMQ resource, due to connectivity issues.

Have you checked that ActiveMQ configuration is correct ? 
Is the service running ? 
Are there any proxies between the app and the MQ instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I see the logs say
"(Communications link failure The driver has not received any packets from the server.)

Check your host and port configuration. Also make sure that the AMQ server is running and listening on port 61616.